# FileTransfer is not defined in ionic 1.3.2

Tags: cordova, file-upload, ionic-framework

I know this issue has already been debated here and on the ionic forum but I can't solve the following issue :

```
ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined
```

I'm using the last version of ionic : 1.3.2 and cordova version 4.2.0
I added both file and file-transfer plugins using the following commands:

```
ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

and I, of course, built the project using

```
ionic build
```

but I still can't manage to make this work even with a sample code.
Each time I access the plugin I get this error.
I tried to start multiple other new projects without any success.

Do you have any solution to that problem ?

Comment: Did you wait for _deviceready_ with the _$ionicPlatform.ready_ before accessing the FileTransfer?

Comment: According to some research this plugin doesn't work from the borwser. It works great from the simulator and I guess from the device too. I have only been testing from the browser since that issue came up.